# High Availability for OTRS

Tags: high-availability, otrs

I need to setup high availability for OTRS or say, i want a backup server which comes up when the main server goes down or a a different server that perform few tasks and the main server performs all other tasks. Please suggest how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by Master-Slave configurations in MySQL...so with this when the Master server goes down, the Slave will serve your request.

Let me know if you have any more questions.